# How to load knockout.observableDictionary plugin in requirejs with shim?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

This is the plugin
https://github.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary

Here is a fiddle showing the problem I am experiencing:

https://jsfiddle.net/L4d84nqc/1/

Code:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
    'ko': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min',
    'ko.observableDictionary' : 'https://rawgithub.com/jamesfoster/knockout.observableDictionary/master/ko.observableDictionary'
  },
  shim: {
    'ko.observableDictionary' : {
        deps: ['ko']
    }
  }
});


require(['ko', 'ko.observableDictionary'], function(ko) {
    console.log(ko);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a way to add a property via the require registration (could be wrong?).  I would simply add the .js file to the bundle, or in the page, and modify the library js like so...

```
require(["ko"], function(ko){    
    (function (ko) {
        function DictionaryItem(key, value, dictionary) {
        .............. all that yummy code
        }
    })(ko)    
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not super experienced with requirejs. What does bundling have to do with this? I thought bundling was for returning multiple modules from one file.

If this is not possible, how do jQuery plugins work ? Is it simply because jQuery supports AMD ?

Comment: It may be possible.  That's the best answer I got for you.  The bundles was just something I mentioned in case thats how you loaded JavaScript on page load